# Vb.net calculator keyboard

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I made a simple calculator in vb.net. So you can type in the text box numbers but there is a problem. The way that +,-,/,* buttons work with this way:When these buttons are clicked then the number get copied to a variable and then the textbox clears. Then you type the second number and then it does the calculation. Add,subtract,multiply and divide are in subs

```
Sub add(num1 As Decimal, num2 As Decimal)
        result = num1 + num2
End Sub
```

So I want to make +/-/*// buttons to work with the same way how can I do that?

Comment: Please provide more explanation and related code you have, then describe what are you looking for. Currently your question seems not clear.

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir I just want to know how to do things when I press +/-/*// keys

Comment: So, you have 4 buttons, one each for add, subtract, multiply and divide. You have one text box. How about adding a second text box for the second number and a label where you can display the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to know how to do things when I press +/-/*// keys

Assuming WinForms, you'd use the `KeyPress` event of your TextBox with the `e.KeyChar` paramter, like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Select Case e.KeyChar
        Case "+"
            Debug.Print("Add")

        Case "-"
            Debug.Print("Subtract")

        Case "*"
            Debug.Print("Multiply")

        Case "/"
            Debug.Print("Divide")

    End Select
End Sub
```